# Cin not read my inputs

Tags: c++, cin

It must be that I'm tired but I can't seem to figure out why my program will not read my cin values for init and end which is supposed to be a start and an end point for my program. The way its setup for input is the first line is the amount of cases then there will be a new line which will be a string then on the next line there will be two integers separated by a space so I feel the way I built it is correct but when I debug the code the values for init and end never change whether I initialize the variable or not.

```
int case_count;
string name;
int init = 0;
int end = 0;

cin >> case_count; 
cin.ignore(numeric_limits<::streamsize>::max(),'\n');
for (int i = 0; i < case_count; ++i) {
    cout << "Case " << i << "\n";
    getline(cin, name);
    cin.ignore(numeric_limits<::streamsize>::max(), '\n');

    cin >> init;
    cin >> end;
```

**Example input**

```
3
flap
1 3
swoop
0 9
flip
0 6
```

Its making it hard to continue with the rest of the code.

Comment: Ignore the call to `ignore()`. Pun intended.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that you call `ignore` in the loop. The problem with this is that [`std::getline`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/getline) extracts (and throws away) the newline character, meaning your `ignore` call in the loop will read and discard the *next* line (the one with the two numbers).

Besides that, when using the input operator to read numbers or strings, the operator will *skip* leading white-space, so even if `getline` didn't read the newline, it would still have worked without the `ignore` call.

However, there is a newline left over in the input stream after you read the numbers, and the next iteration the `std::getline` call will pick up that newline and then `name` will be empty, so you should, as suggested by M.M in a comment, move the `ignore` call to *last* in the loop.

Comment: The `ignore` could be moved to after than `cin >> end`, if this code is in a loop. Otherwise the next loop iteration will fail.  Although it would be more robust to use getline for all lines, and sstream or otherwise to parse.